# What is a stellar laser or stellaser?

Tags: astrophysics

I was watching the latest episode of Isaac Arthur and he was talking about a stellar laser or stellaser which was coined by a scientist named Steve Nixon. I can find no information about stellasers on the internet. What are they and what can they do?

Comment: It sounds like he might be talking about a [maser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_maser).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a Kardashev Type II civilization making their sun lase, and is not about anything observed or predicted in astronomy.

Answer (score 2):

This "laser star" is a hypotethical object in an Asimov short story, which has a special star-like object with very uncommon properties.

But this is entirely Asimov's invention.

In the reality, no such thing was found until now. Not even any similar.

Comment: I've read the short story some decades ago and not on English. I have no idea, what is in the original text. It is probably not "laser star".